# Automation to be run only in the night

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Is there a way I can start schedule an automation to be run for example from 6:00 pm to 12:00 am alone - every day?

Seems to be a basic use case, can anyone tell me if its possible?

I want my automation steps to be repeated every 15 min and fire the contacts in to a journey every 15 min. So the way I have done it is as in the images below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK01w.jpg

However I want this to be run only from 6 pm tp 12 am.

Comment: Have you considered Apex Scheduling??

Comment: You could refer this trailhead (Scheduling Jobs Using the Apex Scheduler) https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_scheduled

Comment: This is a marketing cloud question not Salesforce   Corr @SantanuBoral

Comment: How long does this automation take? I am assuming it's in marketing cloud? Can you tell us more about the use case i.e. Steps in the automation?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty I am trying to do this on SFMC. I am not sure whether Apex scheduling can be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to run this automation hourly, from 6pm each day for 6 occurrences each evening (until midnight). Assuming this is what you want to achieve, then the only way I can think of easily doing this is either:

1. Duplicate the automation 6 times and have the first run at 6pm, second at 7pm, etc.
2. Create a single automation scheduled to run at 6pm daily, with one hour wait periods, then duplicate the automation tasks between the wait periods. Refer to example below.
3. Set the Automation to be a File Drop automation and schedule an empty file (from an external platform) to be dropped into the designated location on your FTP account at the time and frequency that you want to run the automation (note that the file does not need to be used in an automation!)

[image: automation with wait periods]

Comment: Actually I wanted the automation to run every 15 mins. So in the current configuration I have already added 3 wait period of 15 min each as updated in my question

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I have also updated my answer with a third option that you may want to consider.

Comment: Just to make sure that I got your 3rd option right: Do you mean to automatically drop blank files (in every 1 hr schedule - from 6 pm to 11 am) and it kicks of my automation?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Thanks @Eliot Harper. Will try this way and update here if everything goes fine.

Comment: Another option to consider is to have one automation set to run hourly then another automation with a script activity containing an API call to pause it that runs at 12AM every day and another at 6PM that does an API call to turn the automation on.

Comment: @mit88 did that work?

Comment: @Eliot Harper Yes it did work. The only problem is that file dropping is under purview of another team not directly my teams responsibility. So we are becoming a bit dependent on them. Hopefully they would not have to intervene once the drop automation is set up.